# How to make JTable with JComboBox respond only on double click instead of single click

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecelleditor

So this is the first time I tried using `CellEditors` for my `JTable` to embed `JComboBox` and `JSpinner`. Everything works fine as expected wherein I can see the values in `JComboBox` model as well as `JSpinner`'s model values.

However, I noticed that it always displays the `JComboBox`'s values as soon as I make a single click on JTable's column that has the `JComboBox`.

It's not very user friendly because I think the user would prefer to double click on a `JTable`'s column to get the dropdown box values and select values from it *instead of a single click*.

How can I change the `JComboBox`'s behaviour to only display itself on **double** click?

I thought I'd apply a `MouseListener` to the `JComboBox` but I don't know what to do next.

Here's what I've written so far.

```
public class ScheduleDayCellEditor extends DefaultCellEditor{
    private JComboBox jcmbDays;
    private JTable jtblSchedule;
    private DefaultComboBoxModel model;

    public ScheduleDayCellEditor(){
        super(new JComboBox());
        model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[]{"Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri"});
        jcmbDays = new JComboBox(model);
        jcmbDays.setEditable(false);
        jcmbDays.setSelectedIndex(-1);

        jcmbDays.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if(e.getClickCount() == 2){
                    //? ? ? ?
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        return jcmbDays;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return jcmbDays.getSelectedItem(); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
```

Here's a screenshot for additional description.

[image]

I'd appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply override isCellEditable by applying further criterion:

```
@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject aAnEvent) {
    boolean cellEditable = super.isCellEditable(aAnEvent);

    if (cellEditable && aAnEvent instanceof MouseEvent) {
        cellEditable = ((MouseEvent) aAnEvent).getClickCount() == 2;
    }

    return cellEditable;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I didn't know I can override it from within the DefaultCellEditor extended class. It's solved.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't *need* to extend [`DefaultCellEditor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultCellEditor.html) for some other reason, you can simply invoke its [`setClickCountToStart()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultCellEditor.html#setClickCountToStart-int-) method with a `count` of `2`.

```
DefaultCellEditor editor = new DefaultCellEditor(jcmbDays);
editor.setClickCountToStart(2);
jcmbColumn.setCellEditor(editor);
```